# ADS1115 and raspberry pi pico

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython, digital-analog-converter

is there any way to use the ADS1115 with a raspberry pi pico?, I'm in the middle of a project where I need 4 analog inputs but the pico only has 3, I'm using circuit python btw... any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found this on github [ads1115 and raspberry pi pico](https://github.com/guser210/Pico/tree/main/MicorPython/MicroPython%20ADS1115%20Driver%20From%20scratch%20Part%202) i hope it will work for your project!

You can also watch the tutorial on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-C9xnlXKTg&ab_channel=guser210)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So i used [this library](https://github.com/robert-hh/ads1x15).  The ADS1115 just connects to a i2c port and your off to go.  One thing to note that you will need to do single shots for each adc read.  You can only do continues sampling on one channel at a time.

https://github.com/robert-hh/ads1x15